# How to capture output of expect script command with expect_out?

Tags: expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet IP PORT
expect "Escape character is '^]'"
send loadtime
set accum {} 
expect {
    -regexp {..*} {
        append accum "${accum}$expect_out(0,string)" 
        exp_continue
    }
}
puts $accum
```

The output of loadtime command looks like "Load Time: 2.45"
However, on executing the script, $accum only displays "loadtime" and not "Load Time: 2.45"

How to capture output of loadtime command in variable or local file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to press the Enter key: `send "loadtime\r"`